# Spring MVC - JSTL - Session Attribute

Tags: java, jsp, redirect, spring-mvc, jstl

I have a Spring Controller where I am setting a session object with variables .

```
@RequestMapping("/index.html")
public String indexHandler(HttpSession session,
                           HttpServletRequest request,                                         
                           HttpServletResponse response){

          session = request.getSession(true);
          session.setAttribute("country","India");  
          session.setAttribute("url", getAuthURL());//getAuthURL returns a string

     return "tempJSP"; 
    //tempJSP is a JSP under webroot/jsps/ and this is configured in Dispatcher servlet
}
```

tempJSP.jsp

```
//My 2 taglibs are declared here one is core and other is format
<c:redirect url=<%(String)session.getAttribute("url")%> //Here it fails
```

Comment: You'll need to go us more info than saying "Here it fails". *How* does it fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails because a `<% %>` doesn't print anything, the `c:redirect` tag isn't properly closed and possibly also because the value isn't enclosed in quotes. You rather want this:

```
<c:redirect url="<%= session.getAttribute("url") %>" />
```

Note that the cast is unnecessary.

However, using old fashioned *scriptlets* is [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) since a decade. Rather use EL. It's then as easy and nice as:

```
<c:redirect url="${url}" />
```

Comment: Yes you are right Balu. I should not be using scriptlets. Also there was another issue that was there which was selecting the right taglib.I changed it from "<%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jstl/core' prefix='c'%>" to <%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jstl/core' prefix='c'%> That solved the issue